# Find distance from centre of a rectangle to edge through a point

Tags: trigonometry, rectangles

Given a rectangle (or in my example case a square) of width x and height y, which has a centre point q, how can you find the distance from q to the edge of the rectangle through point p, where p is any point in the rectangle? In this question, p is a known position (any point).

Also worth noting that the coordinates systems used is for computer graphics, so top left is 0,0 and bottom right is x,y. I have tried using trig to find the angle between q and p, then trig again to calculate the distance to the edge, but I ran into issues with trig functions in different quadrants.

Example -
[Example drawing with a square of size 128,128 where the length of the purple line is the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4erTF.png)
In this instance, if p was (80, 64) then the output would be 64 (because it is a flat horizontal line from the centre to the outside) and if p was (75, 75) then the output would be ~90.51 (the line would be straight from the centre to the bottom right corner)

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by Y<0? At the bottom right corner, if the rectangle was 128x128, the coordinates would be (128, 128).


I'm not trying to calculate the distance between two points (p and q). I'm trying to calculate the distance between q and the edge of the rectangle through point P. Please see the diagram provided and observe the purple line
If P was on the right edge halfway down then its coordinate would be (x, y/2) you are correct

Comment: Thanks for your response! I believe I said top left is 0,0 and bottom right is x,y. Yeah I understand it's not a normal cartesian plane (which is why I specified that it is different!) The coordinate system is used in a lot of computer programming, including canvases - https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_coordinates.asp

Comment: If you split it into 4 cases, trig solves it instantly. Cosine, done.

Comment: @user2661923 It spans **three** comment spaces. At this point, I would post it as an answer if it is simple. I encourage you to do so.

Comment: The sample has variable sized x and y values, so simply assuming it is square isn't an option.

Comment: I assumed that it is a rectangle of width 2X and height 2Y.  Does this assumption work ok, re the constraints of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the outline of an algorithm as an answer, with the idea that you will fill in the spaces.

The easiest way to tackle this problem is to avoid trig functions, and restrict
your attention to focusing on (x,y) coordinates.  Further, the math will be
**much simpler** if you adopt the following conventions:

1. The center of the
   rectangle has (x,y) coordinate of (0,0).
2. The rectangle has width
   $2 \times X$ and height $2 \times Y$.
3. The upper right hand corner has
   (x,y) coordinate of $(X,Y)$, and the lower left corner has coordinate
   $(-X, -Y).$

The easy way to tackle this is to split the algorithm into 4 cases, depending
on which quadrant point P=(a,b) is in.  I will assume that P is in the first
(upper right) quadrant.  What is needed as a first step is to pretend that you
are drawing a line $L$ from the center thru point P that intersects the rectangle.
All you have to do is identify the (x,y) coordinates of the intersection.  Then,
the Pythagorean Theorem kicks in, so you are done.

Working in case 1, you have to determine whether line $L$ will intersect the
top edge or the right edge.  This determination should be immediate based on
your comparison of the ration (b/a) versus the ratio (Y/X).  So, in case 1,
you have two subcases to work with.  This answer will assume that $b/a) < (Y/X)$
which means that line L will hit the right edge.  The intersection point should
be $\left(X,X \times \frac{b}{a}\right).$  At this point, if I'm not mistaken,
**you are done**.